# NullReferenceException caused by null TermPart.As<AutoroutePart>() in Orchard CMS 1.7.2

Tags: orchardcms, nullreferenceexception, orchardcms-1.7

crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/474456

I'm on Orchard 1.7.2 and I get this error everywhere in my site (which I assume causes the load times to slow down):

```
Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager - NullReferenceException thrown from Action`1 by System.Action`1[[Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.ShapeDisplayingContext, Orchard.Framework, Version=1.7.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

So I traced the issue and found the function public string Slug within TermPart.cs (line 16).

```
   public string Slug {
        get { return this.As<AutoroutePart>().DisplayAlias; }
        set { this.As<AutoroutePart>().DisplayAlias = value; }
    }
```

I found out that `this.As<AutoroutePart>()` is null, and checking out the parts of the Content Item (via `this.ContentItem.Parts`), there is no AutoroutePart. Since it is null, a null reference exception is thrown when trying to retrieve the property DisplayAlias.

See image below:

[image]

Is this a known issue? Any workarounds? Is this what's causing my site to slow down?

Answer (score 1):

Although having these exceptions definitely has an impact on performance I doubt it could cause a noticeable slowdown.

The exception is caused by Taxonomies's TermPart depending on AutoroutePart; i.e. if your content item doesn't use AutoroutePart (what should be pretty rare IMO) then you'll see this exception. Making TermPart depend on Autoroute is a questionable design decision (at least it could use IAliasAspect instead). Please open a bug report about the issue because this should be addressed somehow.

In the meantime you could attach AutoroutePart to the content type in question to get rid of the exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'd rather not attach the ARP to all existing CTs which don't have nor need it. I think updating the TermPart temporarily is more ideal.